# Why doesn't lineFragmentPadding change the NSLayoutManager usedRect size?

Tags: ios, uikit

I've fallen down a bit of a rabbit hole trying to understand how Apple's APIs work for calculating text layout. In the [Text Layout Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001809-CJBGBIBB) there's some example Objective-C code that overrides the default `lineFragmentPadding` and sets it to 0.0:

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:myString] autorelease];
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize: NSMakeSize(myWidth, FLT_MAX)] autorelease];
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[[NSLayoutManager alloc] init] autorelease];
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
[textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:myFont range:NSMakeRange(0, [textStorage length])];
[textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0.0];
(void) [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
return [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer].size.height;
```

The reason given in the docs for setting it to 0:

> Set the line fragment padding to 0 to get an accurate width measurement. (Padding is used in page layout to prevent the text in a text container from abutting too closely other elements on a page, such as graphics.)

Okay, but I do want the `lineFragmentPadding` for exactly the reason they mention, so I followed the example code but didn't use 0.0 (I set it to 5.0, which is the default if you don't override).

```
let textStore = NSTextStorage(string: multilineString)
let textSize = CGSize(width: magicWidth, height: 1000.0)
let container = NSTextContainer(size: textSize)
let layout = NSLayoutManager()
layout.addTextContainer(container)
textStore.addLayoutManager(layout)
container.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
container.lineFragmentPadding = 5.0
```

In the comments above NSTextContainer's `lineFragmentPadding` is says:

> This value is utilized by NSLayoutManager for determining the layout width.

If it's used to set the layout width for text that's wrapping it **seems like it would also adjust the height**. But I started realizing my height calculations were off by small amounts. At first I couldn't understand why, so I created a simple playground with a red overlay to help see the size returned from `layout.usedRect(for: container).size`.

Here it is with `lineFragmentPadding = 0.0`:

[image: lineFragmentPadding 0]

*The size of the red overlay as reported by layout.usedRect(for: container).size is {w 285.697 h 125.062}*

Here it is with `lineFragmentPadding = 5.0`:

[image: lineFragmentPadding 5]

*The size of the red overlay as reported by layout.usedRect(for: container).size is {w 284.582 h 110.742}*

Here's a more exaggerated example with it set to 25.0:

[image: lineFragmentPadding 25]

*The size of the red overlay as reported by layout.usedRect(for: container).size is {w 233.885 h 94.922}*

Changing the `lineFragmentPadding` for the container doesn't change the layout size returned from `layout.usedRect(for: container)` but it does change the actual layout within the textView. I don't understand, **why is the lineFragmentPadding that I can apply to the NSTextContainer not effecting the <del>sizing</del> height returned from the layout manager? I'm expecting a linear relationship - when the width shrinks because of greater `lineFragmentPadding` that *should* cause the height to increase if line wrapping is needed.** It appears the opposite is happening.

*Summary of layout.usedRect(for: container).size Examples:*

`lineFragmentPadding = 0.0`, layout.usedRect(for: container) {w 285.697 h 125.062}
`lineFragmentPadding = 5.0`, layout.usedRect(for: container) {w 284.582 h 110.742}
`lineFragmentPadding = 25.0`, layout.usedRect(for: container) {w 233.885 h 94.922}

**Edit 1:** Added the 25.0 example.

**Edit 2:** Clarified examples to include sizes returned from layout.usedRect(for: container)

Comment: You seem to expect the line length to change. What if you set the line fragment padding more drastically, e.g. to 40? Does the line wrapping change then?

Comment: @matt good call. I tested that before but yes, it's easier to see the difference with larger values so I added another example to the question.

Comment: Right but doesn't that prove that it's working exactly as expected? The lines _are_ shorter. So the layout manager is responding to the line fragment padding of the text container.

Comment: @matt I updated the question with more details about the sizes returned from `layout.usedRect(for: container)`. Looking at the exact rects side by side, the height actually shrinks when the `lineFragmentPadding` increases - which is counterintuitive.

Comment: Does `lineFragmentPadding` really affect top & bottom padding as shown in these screenshots? Other sources and my own experimentation suggest not.

Comment: @nestor you're right it doesn't affect the vertical padding, I only used the gray background instead of white for illustration.